# Cant send values after hiding div

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<div id = "result"> Fade me in and hide div hideme</div>

<div id="hideme">
  <form method="POST">
    Yes<input type="radio" name="name" value="yes"/>
    No<input type="radio" name="name" value="no" checked=true />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="HIDE NOW!" />
  </form>
</div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#result').hide();
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#hideme').hide();
      $('#result').fadeIn(5000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

This will hide my div where the submit is, whenever click on submit it wont send values to PHP. 
How to fix that to make it send the values to PHP so i will get the values from html?

Comment: because you are preventing the default action of the form submit

Comment: if you want to save the state across page loads then you need to store the clicked state in server side or in client(cookie/webstorage)

Comment: You'll have to decide, do you want fancy animations and the trouble of using ajax, or do you just want to submit the form, and drop all the fancy crap, noone is going to sit around for five seconds to wait for the results anyway.

Comment: Your form is not submitting you can use ajax request to send values.

Comment: Though "the trouble of using ajax" is negligible with a lib like jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You have this `e.preventDefault();` in your jquery click handler function. It means that when you press the submit button, the form wouldn't be submitted. It's simply preventing original action of that selector on click.

Here's how to fix it. Use ajax. There's many jquery functions for that, i will show you how to use `$.ajax` method.

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "yourphpscriphere.php",
       data: "name=" + $('input[name="name"]').val(),
       success: function() {
          alert('thank you for using my form');
       },
       error: function() {
          alert('an error happened during the request');
       }
    });

    $('#hideme').hide();
    $('#result').fadeIn(5000);
});
```

Remember to change url to your own. Then you can get your radio button value using `$_POST['name']` in php.

Answer (score -1):

try this code :

html:

```
<div id="result"> Fade me in and hide div hideme</div>

<div id="hideme">
  <form method="POST" id="eform">
    Yes<input type="radio" name="name" value="yes"/>
    No<input type="radio" name="name" value="no" checked=true />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="HIDE NOW!" />
  </form>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#result').hide();
  $('#submit').click(function(e) {
   $.post("page.php",$("#eform").serialize(),function(data){
    $('#hideme').hide();
    $('#result').html(data).fadeIn(5000);
   })
  });
});
```